# Why am I getting a database error that my table has no column named keyword?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting an error that my table Users has no column named keyword, meanwhile it has one and I've defined it at `Users`

User.js

```js
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING,
  password: Sequelize.STRING,
  keyword: Sequelize.STRING, // KEYWORD DEFINED HERE
  date: Sequelize.DATE,
});

sequelize.sync().then(function () {
  User.create({
       name: 'Steve',
       email: 'email@gmail.com',
       password: '123123',
       keyword: 'test', // CALLING IT HERE TO CREATE
       date: 02/1/2020
  })
});
```

The error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: table Users has no column named keyword
```

Comment: What version of sequelize? Have you checked what's inside `sequelize.models`?

Comment: The sequelize version is 5.21.12 and as far as I know it's the latest.